# Requested unknown parameter when using the jquery datatable and add data with ajax call

Tags: datatables

I am using jQuery datatable in my MVC application and first time I send data to it from server and its working fine but when I want update the table with SignalR request then it gives the requested unknown parameter.

**HTML**

```
<table id="tblEmployeeOut" class=" table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>
Id
</th>
<th>
Name
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in employeeOut)
{
<tr>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollNumber)
</td>
<td>
<span> @item.FirstName @item.LastName</span>
</td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
$('#tblEmployeeOut').dataTable({
bLengthChange: false,
"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
sPaginationType: 'full_numbers',
bFilter: false,
bInfo: false,
iDisplayLength: 5,
"language": {
"emptyTable": " No Clients"
},
"aoColumns":
[
{ "sName": "Id" },
{ "sName": "Name" }
]
});
```

In the second image you can see the returned **"Json"** and in third image the alert shown by jQuery datatable.

[image: Table First Time]

[image: Data given with the ajax request]

[image: Alert by jquery]

Comment: have you checked if header table has more column than the data itself ...?
Could you post your JSON data and your DataTables initialisation code?

Comment: I've updated and expanded my answer as fully as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply call

```
datatable.fnAddData(stock); // stock is an array of objects
```

without using mData.

You need to provide other types of input data. (check [this](https://datatables.net/api) and navigate yourself to the specification of fnAddData).

You might want to try a simple function I have just come up with:

```
function objArrayToStringArray(array) {
        return array.map(function (item) {
            return [item["Id"], item["Name"]];
        });
    }
```

and use it like so:

```
var tmp = objArrayToStringArray(stock);
$('#tblEmployeeOut').dataTable().fnAddData(tmp);
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**
if you use `mData` attribute for the columns like this:

```
"aoColumns":
    [
    { "sName": "Id", "mData": "Id" },
    { "sName": "Name", "mData": "Name" }
    ]
```

then you can simply call it easily like you want to:

```
$('#tblEmployeeOut').dataTable().fnClearTable();
$('#tblEmployeeOut').dataTable().fnAddData(stock);
```